# Can't modify Site.Master in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am new to .net technology and I have got one project to update some minor changes.

I just need to add some links to site.Master page and I am not able to change its code. It seems like I can add a new link if I change the page to design view but the change does not reflect in source view.

I am using visual studio 2010

Please help and let me know if you need more information

Comment: Sounds like something may be wrong with Visual Studio if you make changes in design that do not change the source. Can you change regular `.aspx` pages without issue? What happens if you create a new `.master` and try and modify this?

Comment: I can change all other files but not this file even I am able to change Site.Master.vb file

Comment: Have you tried Closing the Program and re-opening? Restarting your Machine and re-trying? or doing a fresh Install and re-trying? I'm afraid I can't really help much more than that on this. If you can edit a newly created `.Master` file then you could try simply copying all of the content of the old master into the new master and replacing the old with the new.

Comment: And the Security attributes for Site.Master via Windows Explorer.

Comment: It shows full access to this file

Comment: Strange thing is I am able to update this file outside the visual studio. I opened it in notepad++ and then I can see the modification in visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running Visual Studio as admin?

Comment: I just run it normally and login as windows Admin. How I could know that I am running Visual studio as admin

Comment: If you can edit other solution files I don't think you have an "Admin" issue.

Comment: Strange thing is I am able to update this file outside the visual studio. I opened it in notepad++ and then I can see the modification in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the visual studio and its working fine :)